# Getting findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths to work?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, data-source

I am copying and pasting a gdb and an mxd into new folders using arcpy.  I then want to change the data sources of the layers in the mxd to point to the new version of the gdb instead of the old one.

My code is:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("pathtomynewmxd")
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths("pathtomyoldgdb", "pathtomynewgdb")
```

this runs successfully, but nothing actually happens.
Additonal info: arcGIS 10.3, the mxd does store relative path names already.

Comment: I would expect to see `mxd.save()` in here - what do you mean by "nothing actually happens"?  i.e. how did you check to see that "nothing actually happens"?

Comment: the layers in the map document do not have any change to their data source, and are still pointing at the same data source as before.  Also, I have tried this with mxd.save() with no change.

Answer (score 4):

You need to save afterwards.

From: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm

```
import arcpy, os
folderPath = r"C:\Project"
for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
    fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
        if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
            mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"C:\Project\Data", r"\\ComputerName\Project\Data")
            mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling myself and doubting functionality. Try to set the value of the ***validate*** parameter to **False** (The default value of the validate parameter ist True).

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("pathtomynewmxd") 
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths("pathtomyoldgdb", "pathtomynewgdb", False)
mxd.save()
```

This will force a change of workspacepath even if it is a not valid one. With using ***validate*** = **False** and no change of the workspacepath - your 'pathtomyoldgdb' might not be valid. If the 'pathtomynewgdb' is not valid it will result in a broken datasource.

In my case the paths were fine but the names of the targeted featureclasses were not identical.

(Remark: I did not try it with relative path names.)